# Unicode error with IPython rmagic; (%%R seems to work but not %R fully)

Tags: r, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to recreate the demo examples on the IPython Notebook rmagic page.  I am getting partial success with a specific error that comes up every time I try to use %Rpush or try to exchange data between R and numpy via the Rpush and Rpull mechanisms (which push/pull data between R and the Py namespaces )

%%R cell magic works reasonably well - I am able to define R vecs X and Y and do a          print (lm(X~Y)) which successfully prints output in an IPython Notebook.  This also works identically on the qtconsole, and the terminal.

Now if I do a plot(X,Y) inside the cell - I successfully get a plot.
If I start a new Notebook line and try plot(X,Y) I get the following error

```
 [....]
 TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

full stack trace at http://pastebin.com/Pb56Tmgc

a) Why is this successful inside a cell but not working in a line?
b) Any suggestions?

(Env: Python 2.7 (Anaconda 2.7.3 CE) R 2.15 rpy2 2.3 MacOSX 10.7.5 on a 2010 MBP 15"

http://www.soundfrost.org/ >youtube to mp3

Comment: this is really weird. have you tried putting in any print statements to see what the dict is?

Comment: It's being triggered by this statement ( see link for trace ).


code = ' '.join(args.code) + code     That's inside the rmagic.py code - it seems to be messing up when converting the code in the linemagic input to a dict rather than a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug - the R magic was getting the local namespace as the argument where it was expecting the cell.

Digging into `IPython.core.interactiveshell` with `git blame`, it looks like it was fixed as part of [pull request #2130](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2130) a few months ago.

Comment: Thomas, thanks much. So I need to run "pre-0.14" dev version to get this? Or latest git repo?

Comment: @Nitin :  Yes. `pre-0.14` or `0.14.dev` refer to the development version on Github.